# jQuery POST executing twice on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, post

In the following code the `$('form').one('submit', ...` only executes once but the `$.post...` bit is called twice as I can see from the network log.

Additionally the callback function is not called either time. I have no idea as to why this is happening or how to fix it, there are no errors reported in the console.

```
$('form').one('submit', function(e) {
    $('form').off();
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!$('button').prop('disabled')) {
        $('button').addClass('loading');
        $('button i').css({opacity: '0'});
        $('button span').css({opacity: '0'}).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
            $('button i, button span').hide();
            $('button').prop('disabled', true).css({backgroundColor: '#f5d76e', color: '#2d2d2d', borderColor: '#f5d76e'});
            $('button svg').css({display: 'block', opacity: '1'});
            $.post('submit.php', {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), message: $('#message').val()}, function(data) {
                console.log('Hi');
                $('button svg').css({opacity: '0'}).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('button i').removeClass('fa-paper-plane').addClass((data.success) ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-exclamation-triangle').css({display: 'block', opacity: '1', marginRight: '0'});
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: might be calling same function at two places.

Comment: Do you mean the form submit function? If so it can only be called once because it uses `.one()`.

Comment: Yeah but you have two nested `one()`. My instinct says it's related. Try adding `.unbind()` before `.one()`.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't imagine this to be the case, it isn't mentioned anywhere in the jQuery docs.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion out though.

Comment: No, that makes no difference, still called twice.

Comment: How many objects does `$('button i, button span')` select? It will attach the event to all selected objects for the specified events.

Comment: Ah, that must be it, it is for two objects!

Comment: I'll just check though.

Comment: That stops the post being executed twice but the callback is still not firing.